# How to use the PySpark CountVectorizer on columns that maybe null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a column in my Spark DataFrame:

```
 |-- topics_A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I'm using CountVectorizer on it:

```
topic_vectorizer_A = CountVectorizer(inputCol="topics_A", outputCol="topics_vec_A")
```

I get NullPointerExceptions, because sometimes the topic_A column contains null.

Is there a way around this? Filling it with a zero-length array would work ok (although it will blow out the data size quite a lot) - but I can't work out how to do a fillNa on an Array column in PySpark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I would drop columns with `NULL` values because there is no useful information there but you can replace nulls with empty arrays. First some imports:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, coalesce, array
```

You can define an empty array of specific type as:

```py
fill = array().cast("array<string>")
```

and combine it with `when` clause:

```py
topics_a = when(col("topics_A").isNull(), fill).otherwise(col("topics_A"))
```

or `coalesce`:

```
topics_a = coalesce(col("topics_A"), fill)
```

and use it as:

```py
df.withColumn("topics_A", topics_a)
```

so with example data:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([(1, ["a", "b"]), (2, None)]).toDF(["id", "topics_A"])

df_ = df.withColumn("topics_A", topics_a)
topic_vectorizer_A.fit(df_).transform(df_)
```

the result will be:

```
+---+--------+-------------------+
| id|topics_A|       topics_vec_A|
+---+--------+-------------------+
|  1|  [a, b]|(2,[0,1],[1.0,1.0])|
|  2|      []|          (2,[],[])|
+---+--------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I had [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744930/failed-to-execute-user-defined-functionanonfuncreatetransformfunc1-string?noredirect=1#comment88498746_50744930), based on comment, I used following syntax to resolve before tokenizing:

## remove the null values

```
clean_text_ddf.where(col("title").isNull()).show()
cleaned_text=clean_text_ddf.na.drop(subset=["title"])
cleaned_text.where(col("title").isNull()).show()
cleaned_text.printSchema()
cleaned_text.show(2)

+-----+
|title|
+-----+
+-----+

+-----+
|title|
+-----+
+-----+

root
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------+
|               title|
+--------------------+
|Mr. Beautiful (Up...|
|House of Ravens (...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 2 rows
```