# Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, countvectorizer

I have generated a DataFrame as shown below

```
   resultWithId = production_df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    resultWithId.show(5, truncate=False)
resultWithId.printSchema()
```

Result:

```
  +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|unigrams                                                                              |id |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|[born, furyth, leaguenemesi, rise, (the, leaguenemesi, rise, seri, book]              |0  |
|[short, tragic, life, robert, peacea, brilliant, young, man, left, newark, ivi, leagu]|1  |
|[mr., beauti, (up, air, book]                                                         |2  |
|[hous, raven, (the, nightfal, chronicl, book]                                         |3  |
|[great, zoo, china]                                                                   |4  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
only showing top 5 rows

root
 |-- unigrams: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

with that result I am trying to use CountVectorizer as below:

```
cv_tmp = CountVectorizer(inputCol="unigrams", outputCol="tmp_vectors")
cv_tmp_model = cv_tmp.fit(resultWithId)
```

However it generates:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-a64deb595190> in <module>()
      1 #remove 20 most occuring documents, documents with non numeric characters, and documents with <= 3 characters
      2 cv_tmp = CountVectorizer(inputCol="unigrams", outputCol="tmp_vectors")
----> 3 cv_tmp_model = cv_tmp.fit(resultWithId)

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
     62                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
     63             else:
---> 64                 return self._fit(dataset)
     65         else:
     66             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):
--> 265         java_model = self._fit_java(dataset)
    266         return self._create_model(java_model)
    267 

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _fit_java(self, dataset)
    260         """
    261         self._transfer_params_to_java()
--> 262         return self._java_obj.fit(dataset._jdf)
    263 
    264     def _fit(self, dataset):

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o893.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 40.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 87, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1076)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1091)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1129)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1132)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:518)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1948)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1158)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer.fit(CountVectorizer.scala:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificMutableProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.takeDestructively(Iterator.scala:1076)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.go(Iterator.scala:1091)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1129)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1132)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:518)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1948)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 15 more
```

I am not sure whats causing this error. I am suspecting "(" in the dataframe, but possibly I am might be wrong as well. In any case, How do I remove that and this working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `resultWithId.printSchema()`

Comment: pault, thanks. added.

Comment: Strictly speaking your code fails upstream, in `Tokenizer` (missing from the question), but the answer is the same - you should get rid of `nulls` first.

Comment: I did remove the null values . I have added a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352675/how-to-use-the-pyspark-countvectorizer-on-columns-that-maybe-null

Comment: Did u find solution ?